# Custom Keyboard for iPhone X inputView.frame size

Tags: keyboard, ios11, xcode9, iphone-x

I have my custom keyboard that's fine with all iPhones except iPhone X. In my custom keyboard i create UI with XIB file and i am not using Autolayout. Here is how i add my keyboard view in Keyboard Extension.

```
self.myKeyX.frame = self.inputView.frame;
[self.inputView addSubview:self.myKeyX];
```

However my keyboard show only in black Area and not showing full keyboard place. Please see in photo. How can i solve it? Thank you.
[Here is photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwwtZ.png)

Comment: hi @Bling you got any solution ?

Comment: Yes. I got it. You need to set anchor point to your Keyboard's View. Add this code. [self.yourKeyboard.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.yourKeyboard.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;

Comment: thanks a lot @Bling.

Answer (score -1):

Following is working for me, on iPhone X

1. xib need to tick "Use safe-area Layout Guides"
2. add constraints to safe-area guides